# Does typecasting if a conditional statement differ from typecasting in a regular C expression?

Tags: c, string, string-literals

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    switch(*(1+"AB""CD"+1))
    {
        case'A':printf("Pulp Fiction");
              break;
        case'B':printf("12 Angry Man");
              break;
        case'C':printf("Casabance");
              break;
        case'D':printf("Blood Diamond");
    }
    return 0;
```

}

This is one C code and it gives output as per the third character in the given string . 
"AB""CD" gives Casabance , "AB""DD" gives Blood Diamond .
I would like to know how the expression in the switch statement calculated ?

While , I tried another code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char ch=*(1+"AB""AD"+1);
    printf("%c",&ch);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives a output 'f' for any changes i make to the string .
I would like to know how this expression is evaluated ?

And why do both above codes differ ??

Comment: Your code invokes UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR, you can't predict it's output reliably.

Comment: @iharob I don't think that's the case here. `"AB""CD"` is just a string literal, and as such, has a clear type (`const char*`), and  there's definite rules on how to add that to integer literals and add integer literals to it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller please read my answer.

Comment: ah you're referring to the `printf` statement, not the actual `switch` condition?

Comment: `"AB""CD"` is the same as `"ABCD"`. Adding 2 will point to the 3rd character.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, passing `&ch` with the `"%c"` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @iharob no question about that. I just thought you were referring to `1+"AB""CD"+1`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No I was not, but I still think it's a ridiculous way to write code.

Comment: @iharob couldn't agree more

Answer (score 2):

There is an important mistake here

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char ch = *(1 + "AB""AD" + 1);
    printf("%c", &ch);
    /*           ^ WRONG ... */
    return 0;
}
```

You are passing `char *` where `char` is expected, that would invoke undefined behaviour. The `printf()` family of function does not define a behaviour when you pass a parameter that does not match the corresponding specifier.

In this case the parameter is a pointer, so

```
printf("%p", (void *) &ch);
```

would print the address of `ch`, but if you want to print the character do

```
printf("%c", ch);
```

Also, `1 + "AB""CD" + 1` is and forgive me a ridiculous way of writing `"ABCD" + 2` it's not wrong and it's 100% valid but it makes you think why, why someone would waste time doing this?

Comment: Can you point out the mistake?? And how is the expression evaluated ?

Comment: @jeet the mistake has nothing to do with the expression, it's pretty much the same as `const char *sting = "ABCD"; switch (string[2])`.

Comment: I had written (1 + "AB""CD" + 1) just for the purpose of checking that the numbers are added normally not . In Java the expressions are type-casted according to the string . Like "A"+1 in a out.print() statement will convert 1 to String type .

Comment: Whell in [tag:c] they're not. Java and c are very different languages, you need to read about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

In this switch statement

```
switch(*(1+"AB""CD"+1))
```

first of all string literals "AB" and "CD" are concatenated by the compiler and as result it looks like

```
switch(*(1+"ABCD"+1))
```

String literals are stored as zero-terminated character arrays. For example in C string literal `"ABCD"` has type `char[5]` (In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So in C++ string literal `"ABCD"` has type `const char[5]`).

In expressions arrays are implicitly converted to pointers that point to the first characters of the arrays.

Thus in this expression `1+"ABCD"+1`  that can be written simpler like

```
2+"ABCD"
```

or

```
"ABCD" + 2
```

there is used the so-called pointer arithmetic. The result of the expression is pointer that points to the third element of the string literal and has type `char *`.

Thus applying dereferencing you get this third character of the string literal.

In this code snippet

```
const char ch=*(1+"AB""AD"+1);
printf("%c",&ch);
```

there is used the same string literal and object `ch` of type `const char` that is initialized by the same third character of the string literal.

However in the statement

```
printf("%c",&ch);
```

you are trying to output the address of the object as a character. It would be correctly just to write

```
printf( "%c", ch );
```

Comment: "ABCD" has type `const char*`, not `char[]`, does it not?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays while in C++ they indeed have types of constant character arrays. The question is marked as a C question is not it?